# Is there a word or concise phrase for "alternative name for something"? (but not pseudonym or alias)

Tags: synonyms

**Question**
Is there a word or concise phrase for "alternative name for something" which doesn't have the associated negative connotation that *pseudonym* and *alias* have? It has to be short so as to fit within a web link.

The negative connotation which I feel is invoked with *pseudonym* and *alias* is something along the lines of "hiding behind a false identity." *Alias* is probably the less negative of the two but if there is a better word or concise phrase altogether I would much prefer to use that. Thanks for your help.

**Some contextual info as requested**
On the website teachers are able to create alternative names for the subject they teach. For example, the default selection is Mathematics but they may want to create an alternative name of Maths, RS instead of Religious Studies and so forth.

Comment: Is this term intended to designate people, objects, abstract entities, or all of these? Perhaps you could supply a little more contextual detail about what you're hoping to identify in this way.

Comment: Nickname. AKA or aka (Also known as.)

Comment: @ErikKowal It is for subject titles. I have added some contextual information to the question.

Comment: @joe92, Anything wrong with "short name" or, as, Joe Dark suggests, "nickname", then?

Comment: These days, the practice is common in all spheres. You could call it the *ID.*

Answer (score 2):

You might try one of:

- ***sobriquet***
- ***moniker***
- ***appellation***

Or another synonym (though I'd avoid *epithet*, because it's accumulated negative connotations).

Answer (score 1):

On the basis of your additional information, I suggest these possibilities:

- **Other name**
- **Abbr. name** *[for 'Abbreviated name']*
- **Short name**
- **Also known as**
- **Also called**

Answer (score 0):

I use the term "short code" (or "shortcode") for this purpose. It's typically a shorter, human-friendly code which stands for a longer name or description.

The term is used with a similar meaning for phone and texting, as well as in web programming.

Answer (score 0):

What about just *nickname*? Or, for your example of "RS instead of Religious Studies", I would say *abbreviation*.