# Names with "The" in them

Tags: grammar, etymology, origin-unknown

What's the term given to names with "The" in the middle of them, for example; "Robert The Red" or "James The Great"?

Comment: [*Sobriquet*, *appellation*, *moniker*](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/210233/55623)...

Comment: ***Soubriquet*** is good and is used here: https://books.google.com/books?id=h9HMCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA46&lpg=PA46&dq=catherine+the+great+soubriquet&source=bl&ots=VpRg-IfQ2v&sig=C6liq9BZ8sfvdyxmDAcAgYXlyqE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiW0OjFsKvNAhVE5SYKHfgYDJUQ6AEIOTAD#v=onepage&q=catherine%20the%20great%20soubriquet&f=false. Wikipedia uses ***cognomen*** for the *[name] the [adjective]* structure (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_monarchs_by_nickname)

Comment: @Silenus a cognomen need not include "the," however; it's just common in English. Also, the Cognomen in Rome became (or at least could become) hereditary, belonging to a family instead of a person, as with *Caesar.* See [Cognomen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognomen) on Wikipedia.  I think *[epithet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epithet)* is the closer match, but again it needn't include *the.*

Answer (score 0):

From the definition of *epithet* (from the Greek *epitithenai*, to add on) in [*Merriam-Webster's Vocabulary Builder*](https://books.google.com/books?id=cyD059eY2RYC&pg=PA43&lpg=PA43&dq=erik%20the%20red%20epithet&source=bl&ots=RQP7OCpS88&sig=9nZgA2P5fMLfbp1nSAv7r9jXXTc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHhLH1y6vNAhUYW1IKHahJA0oQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=erik%20the%20red%20epithet&f=false)
By Mary W. Cornog:

> A descriptive word or phrase occurring with or in place of the name of a person or thing.... Sometimes
>   an epithet follows a given name, as in **Erik the Red** and Billy the Kid.

The definite article specifies the particular person under consideration. There may be many Eriks, but only one is ruddy enough to have *Red* attached to his name as an epithet.